# Parse query into array

Tags: objective-c, database, arrays

In `viewDidLoad`, I have:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Ideas"];   //table name
[query whereKey:@"Hidden" equalTo:@"entry"];              //row should be pulled
[query getObjectWithId:@"Idea"];                          //column name being put into array

ideaArray = [query findObjects];
```

I want it to pull every row that meets the criteria and put it into the array. It works except it only pulls the first 100 rows. In the table, I have 163 rows that meet the criteria, why would this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using Parse with iOS. PFQuery may have the internal limit of a query set to 100 by default. You could increase this limit by setting `query.limit = 1000;` just before you run `ideaArray = [query findObjects];`

For more properties you can set in `PFQuery`, check out the [documentation](https://api.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html)